# In Rails 4 How can I display info from a database based on today's date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am building an app using Rails 4 and postgresql and at the top of the home page I want to show specific content from the database which changes based on the date.  My database is set up as follows:

```
id|question                          |show_month|show_day
01|"question to display on January 1"|01        |01
02|"question to display on January 2"|01        |02
03|"question to display on January 3"|01        |03
```

and so on.

Based on the suggestion made by Frederick, my code now looks like this:

```
On my questions_controller:

def index
  @daily = Question.find_by(show_month: Time.now.month, show_day: Time.now.day)
end

On my View:

<%= @daily.question %>
```

I am getting the following error when I try to load my view. It is calling the error on what I have in my view, above.

```
"NoMethodError in Questions#index" undefined method `question' for nil:NilClass
```

clearly I am not calling it on my view correctly.  Any suggestions on what it should be so that it displays the "question" string from my database?

I was able to get it to display a list of all questions by having @questions = Question.all in my controller and a questions.each do loop on my view, but now I need just one.

UPDATE: The error was caused because I was storing the month/day info as a string.  I made them integers and re-ran my seeds and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Do you want to show only one piece of content per date?

Comment: You can use the `order: 'show_date desc'` in your controller to sort by date.

Comment: Yes, each day would be a different, single piece of content.  Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth would you store a date like that? Please fix your database schema to use the `date` data type. If you want them to repeat every year, use separate smallint columns for month and day.

Comment: Because I'm new and still learning and that's why I asked what would be the best way to store it.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from `@daily.question`? Show more of your view.

Comment: hard to tell without the backtrace - it should tell you which line raised the error and which was the unknown method

Comment: the error is on line 3 of my index.html.erb which is this: <%= @daily.question %> (that is the only thing on the view page). it says "undefined method `question' for nil:NilClass"  Also, I am storing the month/day as a string because it wouldn't let me have a leading 0. do I need to put a .to_i after show_month and show_day?

Comment: The error means that @daily is nil. Don't store show_month/show_day as a string - the leading zero is irrelevant (and is the reason the call to find_by is returning nil)

Comment: that was it!  Thank you SO MUCH! Once I get enough rep I will come back and upvote your answer but I have chosen it as the final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just interested in day/month without year then the easiest may be to replace your `show_date` column with a `show_month` and `show_day` column and store the month/day components in those columns

Your query would then be

```
 Content.find_by(show_month: Time.now.month, show_day: Time.now.day)
```

Comment: oh, that sounds good!  I will play with this for a bit and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this is going to be the solution but I'm having a problem showing it in my view.  I have updated my question to show my new code.